Mockito junit test cases for (Pdf file splitting into images)-Junit5
I want to write junit testcases for the below scenario where pdf file is splitting into images.
 public void upoadImageToBlobStorage(String docsetType, String docPriority, String UserName, MultipartFile file)
        throws InvalidPdfPagesException , InvalidPdfDataException , IOException {

    BlobContainerClient containerClient = azureUtil.getBlobClient();
    
    String fileExtension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(file.getOriginalFilename());
    
    if (fileExtension.equals("pdf")) {

        try (PDDocument doc=PDDocument.load(file.getInputStream())){

            PDEmbeddedFile pde = new PDEmbeddedFile(doc);
            PDFRenderer pdfRenderer = new PDFRenderer(doc);
        
            for (int page = 0; page < doc.getNumberOfPages(); ++page) {

                BufferedImage bim = pdfRenderer.renderImage(page);
                ByteArrayOutputStream byteOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                 ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "jpeg" , byteOutputStream);
                 InputStream imageInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteOutputStream.toByteArray());
                  azureUtil.uploadBlob();
                    
            }
            
            }catch(Exception e){
            
            }       
     }  

 }

TestCase :
  public void upoadImageToBlobStorage() throws Exception {
    
    File file = new File("./src/test/resources/0087.pdf");
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    
    byte fileContent[] = new byte[(int) file.length()];
    inputStream.read(fileContent);
    
    MultipartFile multipart = new MockMultipartFile("0087.pdf", "0087.pdf","multipart/form-data", inputStream);
    
    BlobContainerClient blobContainerClientMock = Mockito.mock(BlobContainerClient.class);
    Mockito.when(azureUtil.getBlobClient()).thenReturn(blobContainerClientMock);
    try {
    service.upoadImageToBlobStorage("application", "normal", "username", multipart);
    }catch(Exception e) {
        
    }
   }

But i am getting IOException in this line
  try (PDDocument doc=PDDocument.load(file.getInputStream())){

File load is not happening. couldnt able to proceed further. Can any one help how to write testcase for this scenario. Thanks.
Dependencies i have used : groupid - org.apache.pdfbox  ArtifactID-pdfbox   version - 2.0.6

Unrelated to your problem: PDFBox is now at 2.0.31.

The problem arises from the fact that MockMultipartFile doesn't provide try-with-resource feature FileInputStream. Whereas, PDDocument.load(InputStream) takes InputStream and tries to consume the resource.
MockMultipartFile.getInputStream() method just returns resource as BufferedInputStream and doesn't provide the expected feature.
One solution is to use a real pdf file instead of a mock. For instance, create a PDF file in your test resources, then reference it in your test case.
If the file is big, or if you don't want to put a real file in your resources, you can create a mock PDF file on the fly.
You might try something like
@Test
public void uploadImageToBlobStorage() throws Exception {

    // Creating a mock PDF file
    PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
    PDPage blankPage = new PDPage();
    document.addPage(blankPage);
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    document.save(byteArrayOutputStream);
    document.close();

    byte[] pdfAsBytes = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    
    MultipartFile multipartFile = new MockMultipartFile("test.pdf", "test.pdf", "application/pdf", pdfAsBytes);
    
    BlobContainerClient blobContainerClientMock = Mockito.mock(BlobContainerClient.class);
    Mockito.when(azureUtil.getBlobClient()).thenReturn(blobContainerClientMock);
    try {
        service.uploadImageToBlobStorage("application", "normal", "username", multipartFile);
    }catch(Exception e) {
        // handle exception
    }
}


In this code snippet, a mock PDF document is created with one blank page, and this PDF is then used as the data for your MockMultipartFile. This 'mock' PDF file should be successfully parsed by PDDocument.load().
